# Mobile Safari Audio Recording from Microphone

Tags: iphone, ios, mobile, safari

I've done quite the searching. I know there's a lot of solutions from PhoneGap that allow people to record audio from the microphone. But what I'm looking for is a solid and simple example of how to record audio via Mobile Safari from a users microphone.

Any examples out there? There's been quite the developments in HTML5.

Answer (score 3):

You can - with iOS6 now - access the camera. Just use

```
<input type="file" capture="camera" accept="image/*" id="takePictureField">
```

I've tried with audio but so far haven't had any luck. I've got a full blog post (which yes, I know Stackoverflow frowns on) demonstrating camera access here: http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2013/5/20/Capturing-camerapicture-data-without-PhoneGap

Comment: HTML Media Capture is supported by iOS 6+ but only for video and picture, not for audio.

Answer (score 0):

Apple doesn't expose the microphone or camera to the mobile browser, but they do expose location based services and motion detection (ios 4.2 and later).

mobile safair info (including location based services) http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/OptimizingforSafarioniPhone/OptimizingforSafarioniPhone.html

accelerometer/motion detection for ios 4.2+
http://www.mobilexweb.com/blog/safari-ios-accelerometer-websockets-html5

Comment: maybe they will expose it sometime in the future? If it's part of the html5 spec then there is a chance it'll happen. You can definitely get access to the microphone from a native ios app, is that an option?