# Looking for a cross-mobile browser compatible way to record from a built in microphone?

Tags: javascript, html, audio, microphone, mobile-browser

I want to make a very simple web app that takes the audio signal from the phone's microphone and varies some simple graphics on the page in as near to real-time as possible.

I'd prefer the app to be web-based (rather than iOS/Android apps) so that users can be directed to the page in a more rapid way. (I.e. go to sh.ort/url and the web app starts straight away)

Is this currently possible?

I'm not sure how well supported the web audio API is, or some of the more modern HTML5 features.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This gives you a nice tutorial on how to record audio through the HTML5 API: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/

Unfortunately, as seen in this post, Apple doesn't support any API for this yet: [Mobile Safari Audio Recording from Microphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6296705/mobile-safari-audio-recording-from-microphone)

Comment: Seems like a complete stumbling block, cross-compatibility is key! Looks like it will have to be an App. Thanks